# Proof of $S^{-1}A\otimes_A M\cong S^{-1}M$ using category theory

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

I'm following these notes [http://math.uchicago.edu/~amathew/chthreeimportantfunctors.pdf](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/chthreeimportantfunctors.pdf) and there the author indicates an alternative proof of the fact that $S^{-1}A\otimes_A M$ and $S^{-1}M$ are isomorphic as $S^{-1}A$-modules.

Firstly, $F(M)=S^{-1}A\otimes_A M$ and $G(M)=S^{-1}M$ defines functors from the category of $A$-modules to the category of $S^{-1}A$-modules. The natural map $(a/s)\otimes m\mapsto (am)/s$ defines a natural transformation from $F$ to $G$.

He then says that this natural transformation is an isomorphism on free modules (which I agree) and that *a standard argument* implies that it holds in general.

What is this standard argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tensor products are left adjoints, so the functor $S^{-1}(A) \otimes_A M$ preserves colimits in $M$, and every module is a colimit of free modules. Localization $S^{-1}(M)$ is also a left adjoint, so it also preserves colimits. So the isomorphism for free modules implies the isomorphism in general.

In fact what we've proven here is something more general, the [Eilenberg-Watts theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eilenberg-Watts+theorem): if $k$ is a commutative ring, $R, S$ are $k$-algebras (not necessarily commutative), and $F : \text{Mod}(R) \to \text{Mod}(S)$ (here we take right modules) is a $k$-linear cocontinuous functor, then it is given by tensoring with an $(R, S)$-bimodule over $k$, namely $F(R)$.

But even this isn't necessary; you can just show very directly, using the universal property of localization twice and the universal property of tensor product once, that $\text{Hom}(S^{-1}(A) \otimes_A M, -)$ is naturally isomorphic to $\text{Hom}(S^{-1}(M), -)$ (and conclude by the Yoneda lemma).

Comment: Very nice answer! Could you just tell me a little bit more about why every module is a colimit of free modules?

Comment: @Gabriel You probably already know how, actually--it's just a way of phrasing that every module can be presented by generators and relations. If $M=\langle g_i: i\in I|r_j: j\in J\rangle$ is a presentation of $M$, then $M$ is the cokernel of the map $\oplus_{j\in J} R\to \oplus_{i\in I} R$ given by $1_j\mapsto r_j$.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you explain how would I use the universal property of localization? I understand that $\hom_{S^{-1}A}(S^{-1}A\otimes_A M,P)=\hom_A(M,\hom_{S^{-1}A}(S^{-1}A,P))$ but I really don't know how to use the universal property of localization. Thank you

Comment: @Gabriel: $S^{-1}(M)$ is the universal module admitting a map out of $M$ on which every $s \in S$ is invertible, and $S^{-1}(A) \otimes_A M$ is the universal module admitting an $A$-bilinear map out of $S^{-1}(A) \times M$. If you work through what this means it is exactly a module admitting a map out of $M$ on which every $s \in S$ is invertible. So the two have the same universal property. You can say this more formally too.